# Integration of the Sequence $\cos^2(nx+u_n)$ over a Measurable Set.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Letting $W\subset[0,2\pi]$ be measurable, and letting $(u_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers, how can it be shown that 
$$\int_W \cos^2(nx+u_n)dx\rightarrow \frac{\mu(W)}{2}$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure? I know that you can begin by linearizing $\cos^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos^{2}t=\frac 1 2 (1-\cos (2t))$ and $\int_W \cos (2nx+u_n) dx =\int_W [\cos (2nx) \cos (u_n)-\sin (2nx) \sin (u_n)]dx  \to 0$ by Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: The trigonometric identity should be $\cos^2 (t)=\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}$.